# primusrun not found when attempting to launch dota2 through steam

Tags: slackware, steam

I am using slackware 14.0, and have gotten all the multilib stuff taken care of. I have skype,spotify and steam running. I have used steam to download Dota2, and when I go to launch the game I get an error --

```
/bin/sh: primusrun: command not found
```

I did a

```
updatedb
locate primusrun
```

Then searched for primusrun, but it wasn't found (using a whereis).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`primusrun` seems to a be a part of [Primus](https://github.com/amonakov/primus), which is apparently some kind of library that that game probably requires. There's a Steam knowledge base article that may help you:

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6316-GJKC-7437